# google earth engine: query the image collection for valid 'scenes'?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to be able to do computations based on 'scenes' using the style of the Landsat Algorithms example in the EE Developer's Guide:

```js
var raw = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_001004_20140524');  
Map.centerObject(raw, 10);
Map.addLayer(raw, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 6000, max: 12000}, 
'raw');
```

from https://landsat.usgs.gov/wrs-2-pathrow-latitudelongitude-converter , I find that my nearest scene center is: path=43, row=36

I can get date_range from my collection with: ee.DateRange(), but I realize that my scene may not exist for date[0] or date[1].

I believe I correctly build my scene ID as:

'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_043036_20180406'

but apparently this image is not in the collection.

```js
Image.load: Image asset 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_043036_20180406' not found.
```

(same result for each day decrementing backwards from the collection Last Modified date (2018-04-27) advertised by the collection info-sheet; I also flipped the path and the row, no help)

```js
var raw = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_001004_20140524');  
// works
```

question: is there a way to query the collection to determine the number of date-stamped images for a specific scene ID?

I don't see something like ee.sceneImageGrabber(collection, path, row) returning a list of dates/images....

or ee.polygonImageGrabber(collection, polygonID) 
also returning a list of dates/images would be nice....

Comment: I confirm that the lat/lon of a point centered in the working map presented by LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_001004_20140524 dropped into https://landsat.usgs.gov/wrs-2-pathrow-latitudelongitude-converter gets path=1 and row=4 (which looks right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Load a Landsat 8 ImageCollection for a single path-row.
    var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 43))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 36));
    print('Collection: ', collection);